# Example of an interesting theorem that fails in intuitionistic set theory but is classically valid?

Tags: set-theory, constructive-mathematics

I'm interested in intuitionistic set theories at the moment. I know that lots of principles imply LEM and so fail intuitionistically, and also a few basic principles - linear ordering of ordinals, for example - fail in intuitionistic set theories. However, lots of classically valid theorems - Cantor's springs to mind - nevertheless go through. Are there any interesting combinatorial bits of set theory that don't work intuitonistically?

Comment: Thanks for this, you are of course right! Removed question as it was not clear. I meant in the context of theories with restricted separation/collection where conservativity on addition of defined relation symbols might be an issue(consider e.g. introducing $\Delta$ relation symbols in intuitionsitc Kripke-Platek set theory. Easy in the classical case - one can prove the resulting extension conservative using DM laws. Can't see it working intuitionistically.)

Comment: May be of your interest this [presentation](http://logic.stanford.edu/~yishuwei/KP.pdf)...

Comment: The book by Johan Georg Granström, *Treatise on Intuitionistic Type Theory* (2011) has a chapter dedicated to *The Notion of Set*.

Comment: In case you are interested; the result is that in most cases introducing $\Sigma$ *function* symbols will be okay. The equivalence with $\Delta$ relation symbols (in the form of their graphs) does not in general remain. See Rathjen & Aczel, notes on constructive set theory, section 19.2 esp 19.2.5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a very nice example from MathOverflow (see [this thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/123482/is-there-a-constructive-proof-of-cantorbernsteinschroeder-theorem), I particularly like Andrej Bauer's well written answer).

> **The Cantor-Bernstein Theorem.** If there is an injective function $f\colon A\to B$ and there is an injective function $g\colon B\to A$, then there is a bijection function $h\colon A\to B$.